# detect desired grep on server using Ansible

Tags: variables, ansible, grep, default

My requirement is to use `grep -E` option in Ansible.

I wish to first use `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` if it is present on the server else switch to `/bin/grep`

I'm looking for a POSIX solutions that works on various shells and operating systems.

Below command works fine on command-line:

```
$ ls /usr/xpg4/bin/grep 2> >(grep -v 'No such file or directory' >&2) || ls /bin/grep 2> >(grep -v 'No
> such file or directory' >&2)
```

Output:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/grep
```

I tried using the above solution in Ansible like below:

```
 - name: "Detect the grep on the system"
   ignore_errors: yes
   command:  "ls /usr/xpg4/bin/grep 2> >(grep -v 'No such file or directory' >&2) || ls /bin/grep 2> >(grep -v 'No     such file or directory' >&2 | head -1"
   register: grepfound
```

In the output it finds both the grep and instead of getting one single preferred `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` `{{ grepfound.stdout }}` prints both the grep which I never wanted.

Output:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["ls", "/usr/xpg4/bin/grep", "2>", ">(grep", "-v", "No such file or directory", ">&2)", "||", "ls", "/bin/grep", "2>", ">(grep", "-v", "No such file or directory", ">&2"], "delta": "0:00:00.013219", "end": "2021-06-14 05:25:52.178385", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 2, "start": "2021-06-14 05:25:52.165166", "stderr": "2>: No such file or directory\n>(grep: No such file or directory\n-v: No such file or directory\nNo such file or directory: No such file or directory\n>&2): No such file or directory\n||: No such file or directory\nls: No such file or directory\n2>: No such file or directory\n>(grep: No such file or directory\n-v: No such file or directory\nNo such file or directory: No such file or directory\n>&2: No such file or directory", "stderr_lines": ["2>: No such file or directory", ">(grep: No such file or directory", "-v: No such file or directory", "No such file or directory: No such file or directory", ">&2): No such file or directory", "||: No such file or directory", "ls: No such file or directory", "2>: No such file or directory", ">(grep: No such file or directory", "-v: No such file or directory", "No such file or directory: No such file or directory", ">&2: No such file or directory"], **"stdout": "/bin/grep\n/usr/xpg4/bin/grep"**, "stdout_lines": ["/bin/grep", "/usr/xpg4/bin/grep"]}
...ignoring
```

I tried using `{{ grepfound.stdout_lines[0] }}` as a workaround but as you see it prints `/bin/grep` instead of `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep`. And if i use `{{ grepfound.stdout_lines[1] }}` it will work here but fail where only one grep is found.

Comment: In general, sniffing out system tooling like that inside of ansible is a code smell; what XY problem do you really have? In other words, if you had a working `grep -E` binary path in some var, what would you then do with it that ansible cannot do right now?

Comment: @mdaniel i need to grep and dump `stdout` for processes containing any of the following three -> `tomcat | weblogic | httpd`

Comment: in ways that `tasks: [ {command: ps auwx, register: ps_out}, {set_fact: { have_t_w_h: "{{ ps_out.stdout | regex_search('tomcat|weblogic|httpd') }}" } } ]` doesn't do for you?

Comment: @mdaniel You suggestion gave the pointer and the below works `tasks: [ {command: ps auwx, register: ps_out}, {set_fact: { have_t_w_h: "{{ ps_out.stdout | regex_findall('.*tomcat.*|.*weblogic.*|.*httpd.*') }}" } } ]`. Could you post this as an answer ? I would have still liked your help use `stdout_lines` instead of `stdout` so that the processes show up better formatted segregated... each process in a new-line. Tried formatting the processes each in a new-line so it looks clean; but could not get it to work. Any suggestions there would be a great help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would have still liked your help use stdout_lines instead of stdout so that the processes show up better formatted segregated... each process in a new-line

That is where [`| select`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#select) comes into play -- it is designed to filter items of a list where the jinja2 test evaluates to true

```yaml
- set_fact:
   example_data:
     stdout_lines:
     - 1111 nothing here
     - 2222 this one is httpd
     - 3333 this one is tomcat
     - 4444 again nothing
- debug:
    msg: |
      the things as a list are:
      {{ example_data.stdout_lines | select('search', '(tomcat|weblogic|httpd)') | list }}

      but you can also fold them back into one str:
      {{ example_data.stdout_lines | select('search', '(tomcat|weblogic|httpd)') | join(nl) }}
  vars:
    # this silliness is to work around a quirk of jinja2 where
    # | join("\n") literally uses `"\n"` to join items :-(
    nl: "\n"
```

produces

```
  msg: |-
    the things as a list are:
    ['2222 this one is httpd', '3333 this one is tomcat']

    but you can also fold them back into one str:
    2222 this one is httpd
    3333 this one is tomcat
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just rely on PATH?

```
- name: stuff
  environment:
    PATH: /usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
  shell: cat something | grep stuff
```

If your binary doesn't exist in the first path, it would check the next one.